# iBeacon ranging in foreground with static library

Tags: ios, static-libraries, ibeacon, cllocation

I have created a framework that takes care of registering CLBeaconRegions and, when in range, ranging the CLBeacons and then send a UILocalNotification. It works as it should when I compile an app with the actual classes, but not when I compile an app with the classes in a fat static library.

What does the framework do:
1. EnterRegion event for the CLBeaconRegion
2. Start ranging
3. Range beacon
4. Deliver UILocalNotification

When testing this in an app that has the actual classes it works in both foreground and background.

When testing this in an app that has the fat library, it works in background, and only **sometimes** in foreground.

Any idea what might be the problem here?